# Is "Did you call me?" not used in close proximity?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> (on an SNS messenger)
>   A: Hi, Joe!
>   (an hour later)
>   B: Did you call me?
>   A: I didn’t call you.

In this situation, is B’s expression not correct? Anybody help!

Answer (score 1):

B's usage isn't wrong with respect to time: if A made a telephone call to B, then B's comment would be correct regardless of when B said it. I wouldn't usually classify something like an instant message or text message as a call, so I might change the wording if A did something like that. If A tried a phone call or tried to start a video chat then B's comment seems perfectly acceptable.